# using Regex in gedit for search and replace

Tags: gedit

I want to replace all occurring characters after comma with );
in a text like this:

```
                    mapMessage.getString("obj_file_path", user_ftp_path + app_path);
                mapMessage.getString("storeid", storeid+"");
                mapMessage.getString("name_farsi", name_farsi);
                mapMessage.getString("name_english", name_english);
                mapMessage.getString("group", group+"");
                mapMessage.getString("price", app_price+"");
                mapMessage.getString("icon", icon);
                mapMessage.getString("app_path", app_path);
                mapMessage.getString("desc_farsi", desc_farsi);
                mapMessage.getString("desc_english", desc_english);
                mapMessage.getString("isfarsi", isfarsi);
                mapMessage.getString("tags", tags);
                mapMessage.getString("shot1", shot1);
                mapMessage.getString("shot2", shot2);
                mapMessage.getString("shot3", shot3);
                mapMessage.getString("shot4", shot4);
                mapMessage.getString("shot5", shot5);
                mapMessage.getString("changes_fa", changes_fa);
                mapMessage.getString("changes_en", changes_en);
                mapMessage.getString("upload_real_address", upload_real_address);
                mapMessage.getString("apk_upload", apk_upload);
                mapMessage.getString("app_upload_valid_shot", app_upload_valid_shot);
```

so after the replace was done for example the first line should looks like:

```
mapMessage.getString("obj_file_path");
```

Comment: If there is no solution in gedit, please let me know what app is suitable for doing the job in linux (ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to do a search-and-replace for **,.*$** with **);**

Make sure the "Regular expression" checkbox is selected.